# .gitignore file is not working in my project

Tags: git

I have a project named "shortcut", here is my issue & steps

```
cd shortcut
vim .gitignore 
git init
git add *
git status
```

I could still see all the .exe files and .pdb files are in the staging. what's wrong with my git operation steps ???

here is my .gitignore file

```
[Dd]ebug/
[Dd]ebugPublic/
[Rr]elease/
[Rr]eleases/
*.exe
*.pdb
*.dll
```

Comment: What Git version? Newer ones handle explicitly adding ignored files better.

Comment: my version is 1.9.5.github.0

Comment: are your .exe files in the `shortcut` folder, or in one of the listed folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confused, although it's hard to tell exactly where. Consider the following:

```
$ mkdir shortcut
$ cd shortcut

$ touch foo
$ echo foo > .gitignore

$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ~/shortcut/.git/

$ git add *
The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
foo
Use -f if you really want to add them.
fatal: no files added
```